# How to run the schedule class for every one minute How to schedule the schedulable class for every one minute

Tags: apex

How to run the schedule class for every one minute
How to schedule the schedulable class for every one minute

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this by using the [System.schedule](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_scheduler.htm) method.

The code below will get your scheduled job to run every minute

```
String sch = '0 * * * * *';
System.schedule('My Jobs scheduled name', sch, new MyJob());
```

The schedule is in the format

> Seconds - Minutes - Hours - Day_of_month - Month - Day_of_week - optional_year

See [here](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_scheduler.htm) for more information.

Comment: I don't believe this is correct. Schedule can be set for every hour and less granular, but not for every minute and more granular.

Answer (score 1):

```
Setup > Develop > Apex Classes > Schedule Apex
```

Should get you to the menu that schedules a class to run at specific times.